I installed Postgresql. While trying to create user in psql, I messed up the configuration settings. Now, I can't even uninstall or install completely

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jammy-pgdg/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

The above mentioned was the error I'm getting while I do sudo apt-get update. Can anyone explain me on uninstalling and installing psql.
In addition, I also get

W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

These warnings after performing steps that are available on public forums.

Nowhere it's mentioned which distro you're running. We may infer it's Ubuntu 22.04 but you must confirm this. Now, installing PostgreSQL in Ubuntu is as easy as following the OFFICIAL docs: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install-and-configure-postgresql . It seems that instead you've added 3rd party repos. So just remove the ones m3entioned in the error messages and you should be able to update the OS, for starters.

Thank you for your response @ChanganAuto. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 as u said I was using third party repos. Now my issue is while I try to install using official docs, I can't install it. And I don't even know how to remove the previously installed repos. Can u provide any help regarding that?

Please add this and any other requested information to the question itself, not just down here in comments. Your goal is to make your main question post as clear and complete as possible, as a good question is more likely to attract good answers.
